# DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A3 NO AUTHENTICATE failed

Tags: java, imap

I'm connecting to IMAP server with java code:

```java
        String host      = "outlook.office365.com";
        String port      = "143";
        String username  = "user@comp.com";
        String password  = "password";

        Properties props = System.getProperties();

        props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", port);
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.host", host);

        //SSL
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");

        props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "com.boomi.connector.mailsdk.connection.MailSSLSocketFactory");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", port);

        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator()
        {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
            {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username , password);
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
        session.setDebug(true);
        System.out.println(session);
        Store store = session.getStore("imap");

        System.out.println(store);

        store.connect();
```

Problem number one:

1. it takes imap store as imap://windows_user@outlook.office365.com
2. failing to connect

log:

> DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.2 javax.mail.Session@6433a2
> DEBUG: getProvider() returning
> javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
> DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384 DEBUG IMAP:
> mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false DEBUG IMAP:
> mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000 DEBUG IMAP:
> mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1 DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
> DEBUG IMAP: enable STARTTLS DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
> imap://windows_user@outlook.office365.com DEBUG IMAP:
> protocolConnect returning false, host=outlook.office365.com,
> user=windows_user, password= DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect
> to host "outlook.office365.com", port 143, isSSL false
> OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [QQBNADYAUABSADAANABDAEEAMAAwADEANAAuAGUAdQByAHAAcgBkADAANAAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBvAHUAdABsAG8AbwBrAC4AYwBvAG0A]
> A0 CAPABILITY
> CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 LOGINDISABLED STARTTLS SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+ A0 OK CAPABILITY
> completed. DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login,
> host=outlook.office365.com, user=user@comp.com,
> password= A1 STARTTLS A1 OK Begin TLS negotiation now. A2
> CAPABILITY
> CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+ A2 OK CAPABILITY
> completed. DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH2 DEBUG
> IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed DEBUG IMAP:
> AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A3 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.

Comment: Resolved. The user was blocked.